# Spring-Integration using Jdbc-Templates, for operations such as batch-Updates?

Tags: java, datasource, spring-integration, jdbctemplate, batch-updates

This question is regarding ["Spring Integration"](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) using JdbcTemplates and not usual Spring with JdbcTemplates (for which several examples are available on the web).

I have been following up with [documentations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html) and [examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jdbc) for Spring-Integration with JDBC Outbound Gateway. These all are fine for basic sql queries. Also the documentation says that Spring-Integration can work either with dataSource (examples provided) or a jdbcTemplate (examples not provided).

Basically, I wanted to know, if we want to implement a batchUpdate (which is available in jdbcTemplate), how should we specify? Lets say, if we have the following [Spring-Context](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/jdbc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration does not currently support batch JDBC updates. But, you can easily use a `JdbcTemplate` within your code (a POJO) and invoke it using a `<service-activator/>`.